# Configuring next-optimization-images

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm having issues configuring next-optimization-images library. I'm doing a static export site where frontend will be in s3 and hit lambda api endpoints so I can't use built in next/image optimization. I need to configure a loader. Currently I'm testing a png and when I configure the next.config.js file I'm getting `The root value has an unexpected property, handleImages, which is not in the list of allowed properties`, but per the docs handleImages is what I need to configure a PNG. So what am I missing. Maybe there's a better free loader that I can use. I'm new to nextjs so I appreciate any help!

```
// next.config.js
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [
    optimizedImages,
    {
      handleImages: ["png"],
    },
  ],
  { output: "export" },
]);
```

Comment: next-optimized-images does not seem to be fully compatible with Next 13 for now (according to https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images/issues/287)